# MYSQL / PHP - How to check a 2nd query to check checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 queries.  The first get a list of values from one table to display as row of checkbox options.
The second query gets all date from another table based on the userid.

```
$query = $con -> prepare ("SELECT * FROM Periods");
$query -> execute();
$query2 = $con -> prepare ("SELECT * FROM Availability WHERE Users_user_id = :userid");
$query2 ->bindParam(':userid',$user_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query2 -> execute();
```

I then display the values of $query1 as:

```
while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo  "<div class='form-check form-check-inline'>
        <input class='form-check-input' type='checkbox' name='periods[]' value='".$row['P_Title']." ' checked>
            <label class='form-check-label nowrap'>".$row['P_Title']."</label>
                </div>";
  }
```

At the end of the 3rd line I have ' checked> which is basically just checking every checkbox.However I need to replace this with some code to check if the 2nd query contains the same ID and if so check the box otherwise leave it unchecked.

So, the Periods table has a P_ID and the Availability table has a P_ID (FK) so as the list of Periods is being displayed I need to check if the P_ID is also in the Availability table and check the checkbox.

Hope I explained it correctly.

Comment: you need to perform a `UNION` in your `SELECT` to combine the results of the two tables. Then you simply do `if( $row['table1_field_id'] === $row['table2_field_id'] ) { echo 'checked'; }`

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to perform a `UNION ALL` to combine the results of the two tables, then revolve the logic around a statement that set the checked property of your checkboxes when `table1.id === table2.id`.

**Example:**

```
<?php
$sql  = "SELECT * FROM Periods";
$sql .= "UNION ALL";
$sql .= "SELECT * FROM Availability WHERE Users_user_id = :user_id";

$query = $con -> prepare ($sql);
$query ->bindParam(':userid',$user_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query -> execute();

while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo   "<div class='form-check form-check-inline'>
                <input class='form-check-input' type='checkbox' name='periods[]' value='".$row['P_Title']."'"; if($row['Periods.P_ID'] === $row['Availability.P_ID']){ echo "checked"; } echo " />
                <label class='form-check-label nowrap'>".$row['P_Title']."</label>
            </div>";
}
?>
```

You will also need to specify the table for the other `$row['some_field']` if they are duplicate occurrences in both tables.

Comment: Thanks Martin.  I tried your solution but mysql is returning the data on 1 column:
P_ID
1
2
3
4
1
4

Comment: Is the PK and FK the exact same name? Because that's when you need to define the table alongside the name, else it doesn't know which id it is.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using 2 querys and an in_array function:

```
  $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
     
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Periods";
$sql2 = "SELECT Periods_P_ID  FROM Availability WHERE Users_user_id = :user_id";     
$squery2 = $con -> prepare ($sql2);
$squery2 -> bindParam(':user_id',$user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$squery2 -> execute();
  
while ($row2=$squery2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
       $ids[] = $row2['Periods_P_ID'];
   }

$query = $con -> prepare ($sql);
$query -> execute();

while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   echo  "<div class='form-check form-check-inline'>
       <input class='form-check-input' type='checkbox' name='periods[]' value='".$row['P_Title']."'"; 
   if (in_array($row['P_ID'], $ids)){ echo "Checked"; } echo ">
             <label class='form-check-label nowrap'>".$row['P_Title']."</label>
             </div>";
  }
```

So this has the desired affect.
Next task is to update the Availability table to insert new checked items or to remove current ones if they have been unchecked.  Hope this will be easier :)